# stick a div to the bottom of the page

Tags: css, positioning, html

I am trying to use the 'position: relative;' 'position: absolute; bottom: 0;' thing to stick a div to the bottom of the page, but it keeps hanging right under the lowest visible element within the container. I tried changing 'height' and 'min-height' properties for relevant divs but never got it to work properly. it either disappears or places itself below all containers (including the footer) just sitting on plain background, or just hangs right under lowest element in the container.

here's my CSS:

```
#body {
   padding-bottom:40px;   /* Height of the footer */
    padding-top: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.sink{
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

.sink is the class of the div I need to stick to the bottom.

div with id body is contained within div with id container, which is contained withing html body:

```
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
    background: #7092BE;
    background-image: url("bg1.png");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I hope I copied all the necessary info, tell me if not please.

Comment: Maybe 'position:fixed' would help...

Comment: i got same problem like this try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929220/get-footer-bootom-of-the-page

Comment: can you post a demo at jsfiddle.net

Comment: here's a jsFiddle with the hole code: http://jsfiddle.net/mcxvM/
I'm not very familiar with jsFiddle, I hope it works right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - I gave the div right above 'sink' (and not the one containing it) the 'position: relative;' and it worked. Thanks to everyone.